# In Qt "no matching function for call to 'connect'" An error occurs

Tags: c++, qt

If I create a project with Qt Quick Application-Empty in Qt5.12.5, it will be created in the main.cpp file from the start of creation.
"no matching function for call to 'connect'" An error occurs.

I've searched the problem on both google and stack overflow but didn't find the right result.
This is the first time I've encountered an error since I created a project.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, // no matching function for call to 'connect'
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

"no matching function for call to 'connect'" Is there a way to fix it?

I have not started any programming, but I will get this error from project creation.
I don't know why.

I'm wondering what behavior the syntax that caused the error exists for.
If it's not important, I wonder if it's okay to delete it.

Add some error pictures.

main.cpp

[image]

complie message

[image]

.pro

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce (Linux + Qt5.13.1).

Comment: What compiler on what OS?

Comment: The current environment is doing a cross compile build on raspberry pi using qt on ubuntu18.04.
The compiler uses gcc-linearo-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64 for Raspberry Pi, not gcc.

Comment: I would suggest to post the actual compiler error as well

Comment: There is no compiler error
There is no problem in build and run, but in main.cpp it causes problems like the code above
The red line tells main.cpp that an error has occurred, but I can't tell it's running.
Perhaps it ignores the error and runs.
It is also questionable that this behavior is possible.

Comment: I tried to [google "qt5 "no matching function for call to 'connect'" site:stackoverflow.com"](https://www.google.com/search?q=qt5+%22no+matching+function+for+call+to+%27connect%27%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com) and got a variety of hits. May be, something simple like `CONFIG += c++11` in your `.pro` file could help. But, I still don't understand _There is no compiler error_. This is Qt5 signal/slot style and errors should be recognized at compile time (in opposition to the old signal/slot style which is resolved at runtime). Are you sure that you don't run old binaries beside of compiler errors?

Comment: I already have CONFIG + = c ++ 11 added to my .pro file.